# Como resetar CSS de vários arquivos HTML incluídos por require

Tags: php, html, css, html5, include

Por sugestão [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/465/23400), estou tentando utilizar o [`normalize.css`](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css) pra zerar os estilos entre um `require` e outro, mas não tem jeito, a CSS do arquivo posterior interfere completamente no layout do arquivo anterior. Isso não altera o resto da página, o problema é apenas entre eles.

Se coloco apenas um arquivo tudo bem, fica perfeito, mas quando incluo outro dá problema entre eles.

O HTML com o PHP:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <?php
                require "arquivo1.html";
            ?>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">

           <?php
                if ($var1 == "incluiarq");
                require "arquivo2.html";
            ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div
```

O `arquivo1.html` (o arquivo2 é basicamente igual, mas com as CSS diferentes):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/normalize.css">

<style type="text/css">

    ol{margin:0;padding:0}.c1{widows:2;orphans:2;text-indent:86pt;text-align:justify;direction:ltr}.c6{max-width:468pt;background-color:#ffffff;padding:72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt}.c0{font-size:12pt;font-family:"Times New Roman"}.c5{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}.c8{font-size:14pt;font-family:"Times New Roman"}.c2{font-weight:bold}.c4{text-decoration:underline}.c3{height:11pt}.c7{font-style:italic}.title{widows:2;padding-top:0pt;line-height:1.15;orphans:2;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-size:21pt;font-family:"Trebuchet MS";padding-bottom:0pt;page-break-after:avoid}.subtitle{widows:2;padding-top:0pt;line-height:1.15;orphans:2;text-align:left;color:#666666;font-style:italic;font-size:13pt;font-family:"Trebuchet MS";padding-bottom:10pt;page-break-after:avoid}li{color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial"}p{color:#000000;font-size:11pt;margin:0;font-family:"Arial"}h1{widows:2;padding-top:10pt;line-height:1.15;orphans:2;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-size:16pt;font-family:"Trebuchet MS";padding-bottom:0pt;page-break-after:avoid}h2{widows:2;padding-top:10pt;line-height:1.15;orphans:2;text-align:left;color:#000000;font-size:13pt;font-family:"Trebuchet MS";font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:0pt;page-break-after:avoid}h3{widows:2;padding-top:8pt;line-height:1.15;orphans:2;text-align:left;color:#666666;font-size:12pt;font-family:"Trebuchet MS";font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:0pt;page-break-after:avoid}h4{widows:2;padding-top:8pt;line-height:1.15;orphans:2;text-align:left;color:#666666;font-size:11pt;text-decoration:underline;font-family:"Trebuchet MS";padding-bottom:0pt;page-break-after:avoid}h5{widows:2;padding-top:8pt;line-height:1.15;orphans:2;text-align:left;color:#666666;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Trebuchet MS";padding-bottom:0pt;page-break-after:avoid}h6{widows:2;padding-top:8pt;line-height:1.15;orphans:2;text-align:left;color:#666666;font-style:italic;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Trebuchet MS";padding-bottom:0pt;page-break-after:avoid}

</style>

<p class="c1">
    <span class="c2 c8">Loren</span>
</p>
<p class="c1">
    <span class="c0">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p class="c1">
    <span class="c0">.</span>
</p>
<p class="c1">
    <span class="c0">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p class="c1">
    <span class="c0">Loren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsum</span> <span class="c0 c2">Loren ipsum</span></p>
<p class="c1">
    <span class="c0">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p class="c1">
    <span class="c0">Loren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsum</span>
</p>
<p class="c1">
    <span class="c0">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p class="c1">
    <span class="c0">Loren ipsum,</span> <span class="c0 c7">data venia,</span>
    <span class="c0">Loren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsum</span>
    <span class="c0 c2">Loren ipsumLoren ipsumLoren ipsum</span>

</p>
```

Estes arquivos eram originalmente `docs` feitos no google drive, e foram convertidos pra HTML pelo próprio google drive, então ele gera este monte de css, mas de forma surpreendente fica perfeito :-) quando incluo apenas um.

Este que postei acima (`arquivo1.html`) é o arquivo inteiro que estou incluindo, eu retirei todo o cabeçalho e as tags de fechamento pra que não interferisse, e se coloco apenas um tudo bem, mas quando coloco o segundo  dá problema. Alguma ideia?

Comment: remove o css inline das páginas e cria uma arquivo pra cada `style`, na hora de incluir inclua o css referente à cada arquivo

Comment: @ErlonCharles Você diz criar um arquivo CSS com a formatação que vem no arquivo HTML? Tentei isso mas não funcionou, ele continua sobrepondo as CSS's.  Ou vc diz criar um arquivo css só e aplicar em todos de acordo com as classes? O problema, se for isso, é que ele cria atributos diferentes para as classes... Por exemplo .c1 num arquivo é `.c1{
    font-size:14pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-weight:bold}` enquanto no outro é `.c1{
    widows:2;
    orphans:2;
    text-indent:86pt;
    text-align:justify;
    direction:ltr`

Comment: Em tempo: testei utilizando arquivos externos com e sem o normalizecss... Com normalize usei assim no início do arquivo `<link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/normalize.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="arquivo1.css">`

Comment: Só pra constar, até encontrei uma <s>forma</s> gambiarra pra contornar isso, que foi usando um plugin do google drive pra mesclar todos os arquivos em um só, e depois gerei apenas um arquivo HTML. Daí poderia usar esta CSS pra todos os arquivos individuais (depois de separar de novo o arquivo mesclado), mas quer saber, achei que ia ficar uma bela porcaria, e decidi reescrever  tudo, usando poucas tags, e pouco CSS, afinal, é só um arquivo de texto, não tem sentido usar todo esse CSS e esse HTML doido que o google drive gera.

Answer (score 1):

Isso possivelmente se da por conta de especifidade do seu arquivo .css sobrescrevendo **seletores de tipo**. Aconselharia linkar no arquivo .html principal o **normalize .css (apenas para reset)** e outro .css para **gerir responsabilidades de estilo** Ex: (**main.css**) e nesse arquivo fazer um import de **dois .css** com responsabilidades diferentes de estilização tipo: (**doc-1.css e doc-2.css**)

Arquivo .html
...

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
```

Arquivo .css...

```
@import "../doc-1.css";
@import "../doc-2.css";
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, quando tiver um tempo vou testar e retorno aqui. +1

Comment: @gustavox Apenas um adendo lembre-se que os **.css dos docs** não podem ter as **mesmas classes** se não realmente sempre vai sobrescrecer e o que vai **prevalecer** é a **especifidade do seletor** . Uma saida é definir um prefixo para classe de cada doc. Ex: `.doc-c1, .doc2-c1`...  E injetar isso via javascript. Abs.