# Existem tags de edição de texto em HTML "preferidas" pelos robôs de busca do google?

Tags: html, html5, seo

Decidi reescrever uns 300 arquivos que vou utilizar num projeto, pois eles foram escritos originalmente direto no google docs, e quando salvo como HTML e [tento incluir com `require`ou `include`, as CSS's interferem entre si](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66902/como-resetar-css-de-v%C3%A1rios-arquivos-html-inclu%C3%ADdos-por-require) (e tbm porque gera um monte de CSS inútil, o HTML é todo zoado com um monte de classes...).

Enfim, como são muitos e ainda tendem a aumentar, estou tentando utilizar as "melhores" `tags` pra reescrever estes arquivos, e pesquisando encontrei várias páginas com a mesma afirmação:

> A tag recomendada para o SEO é o strong em inglês strong significa
>   forte ou seja, vai deixar a palavra forte e bold significa negrito,
>   então se você usar b em suas postagens será apenas uma palavra em
>   negrito e não uma palavra que deva ser diferenciada pelos robos de
>   buscas da google.

Isso não fez muito sentido pra mim. Que diferença isso pode fazer na ordem de resultados das pesquisas por exemplo?

Eu já estava utilizando `<strong>`, e fui pesquisar porque comecei a pensar em fazer com `<b>`, economizando assim tempo de digitação, tamanho do código etc. (inclusive tem [esta pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32289/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-sem%C3%A2ntica-entre-em-e-strong-eles-substituem-i-e-b) que explica bem a diferença semântica, mas não aborda  a relação disso com [seo](/questions/tagged/seo)).

Então o que gostaria de saber é se realmente existe diferença na utilização de tags de edição de texto HTML (de grifo, itálico ou qualquer outra) para SEO, e qual o resultado prático disso.

Uma página vai ficar melhor rankeada nos resultados por deixar de usar `<b>` e passar a usar `<strong>` por exemplo?

Comment: Visualmente falando `<b>` é igual a `<strong>` que é igual a `<span style="font-weight: bold">`. Diziam antigamente que `<strong>` era a melhor opção para SEO, mas parece que hoje em dia não faz diferença, sendo o conteúdo em si que faz a diferença. Veja [esse comentário](http://goo.gl/xtOIOy). Também dê uma olhada no [guia de SEO do Google aqui](http://goo.gl/5Xz9iD).

Comment: Então, eu também achava  que só o conteúdo fazia diferença, mas depois de ver tantas vezes essa afirmação fiquei em dúvida... Vi que aquele comentário remete a um vídeo do Matt Cuts, mas meu inglês :/ Ele fala que não faz diferença? To lendo aqui o guia, valeu, não tinha me aprofundado ainda em SEO, e to achando muito legal. Se quiser postar como resposta vale pelo menos +1. Abraço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Google não diz nada sobre esse aspecto, mas isso não irá contribuir nada para o SEO.
As coisas mais importantes a considerar é a **estrutura da página** (usar tags corretamente, H1 para cabeçalhos, secções, etc...), **meta tags** e **URLs**.

É a mesma coisa que usar `classes/ids` com nomes descritivos no `HTML/CSS` como por exemplo, se eu tivesse uma loja de animais e estiver a utilizar `classes` e `ids` como no exemplo abaixo, isto só vai fazer com que o código fique mais bonito e seja mais fácil e claro para a sua leitura. Mas não irá ajudar no SEO:

```
#menu.gato.cao { ... }
#menu.avestruz.animais.etc { ... }
```

O Google prefere sites que carregem rápido, que têm boa estrutura e que têm URLs descritivos. Estes são os aspectos nos quais nos devemos focar.

Podes ler mais informações sobre este tópico em: [**Você precisa de um SEO?**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291?hl=pt)

Comment: Então não faz diferença mesmo... valeu.+1 Só complementando, você tem alguma ideia de qual a chance de uma delas ser depreciada em função da outra no futuro? Por exemplo, vc apostaria que a `<b>`ou a `<strong>` irá "sobreviver"? (Nem vou abrir uma pergunta sobre isso porque a resposta seria baseada em opinões etc e a pergunta rapidamente seria fechada hehe)... Nem precisa explicar, só pra ter uma ideia mesmo... Valeu.

Comment: É verdade, acho que será mais baseada em opiniões. A minha opinião sobre isso é que nenhuma delas irá desaparecer, assim como o `<i>` também já esteve para ser removido e não o chegaram a remover.